# How do I pass a system-defined Elastic Beanstalk environment variable (HOSTNAME) to an EC2 Docker container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Elastic Beanstalk application, managing some EC2 instances.

I would like to pass the environment variable `HOSTNAME` from the EC2 instance to the Docker container running on it. I can remote into the instance and `echo $HOSTNAME`, but I'm not sure how to pass the value to my app's Docker contianer.

[The AWS docs describe how it passes environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.container.console.html#docker-env-cfg.env-variables), defined in the UI, when using Docker Compose, but it doesn't describe how it works for a non-Compose setup.

How can I pass `HOSTNAME` to the container running on EC

Platform: `Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.6.5`

Answer (score 0):

(Tested on `Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.6.5`)

Having a poke around in the logs for an EC2 instance, looking in `eb-engine.log`, you should find a line like this:

```
2023/12/17 14:05:13.328497 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c docker run -d --env-file /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env.list   3a15af993d32
```

Looks like Elastic Beanstalk will store environment variables in a file at `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env.list`. We just need to modify this file before the container starts.

---

You will need to make use of [two platform hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html#platforms-linux-extend.hooks). One will run on any application deployment. The other will run on any config deployment.

- In your codebase, create the directories `.platform/hooks/predeploy` and `.platform/confighooks/predeploy`.
- Add a bash script file to each directory. I called mine `01-env-var-passthrough.sh`. Paste this code into it:

  ```bash
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  set -o errexit -o nounset -o pipefail -o verbose

  # Append a new line to the EC2 instance's environment variables
  envfile="/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env.list"

  echo "" >> $envfile
  echo "HOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME" >> $envfile
  ```
- Ensure the `.platform/` directory is included in your bundled application zip.